# Inserting date in sqlite db using adobe air and javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, air, julian-date

I am trying to insert a date value in sqlite db using air and javascript. The value gets inserted but when I try and view it, it says null.

Later I found that SQLite stores date using julian format. How to convert a javascript date object to julian format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe AIR does not support the JS date object. While inserting data I was using

```
stmt.parameters[":myDate"] = new Date();
```

This was inserting the date in the database but was not returning it in a useful format. I tried the following and it worked like charm.

```
stmt.parameters[":myDate"] = new window.runtime.Date();
```

[Ref Here](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/08/06/what-are-your-biggest-issues-with-adobe-air/)

Answer (score 0):

I got something.

Inserting the data in to SQLite:

```
 INSERT INTO <table> (<column>) VALUES (’2008-06-09 07:20:00′);
```

here, the important thing is - `<column>` data type should be DATETIME.

Fetching the data back from SQLite:

```
SELECT datetime(<column>) AS <variableName> FROM <table>;
```